# ASP .Net core 3.1 connection string

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

what is the correct way do define my connection with an already existing database on a server with SQL server authentication?

Comment: The [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=sqlclient-dotnet-core-3.1) lists the available connection string keywords. Specify at least "Data Source", "User ID", "Password", and "Initial Catalog".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define in **appsetting.json** and using "Options pattern" we can get Connection String.

Refer below link for "Options pattern"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0